# FluentNhibernate: Configure Database in XML

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible, to configure the Database connection the classic way in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, but use FluentNhibernate to map the entities?

What I tried is combining the classic `configuration.Configure();` somehow with `Fluently.Configure()`, but I could not figure out a way yet.

Why would I want that? Because I'd like to deploy the same binaries to different customers running databases from various vendors. Thus I want to avoid compiling binaries for each supported database dialect. Maybe there is even a better approach than the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the nhibernate configuration normally, the use it with Fluently.Configure :

```
 // read hibernate.cfg.xml
 Configuration config = new Configuration().Configure();
 // load mappings from this assembly
 Fluently
      .Configure(config)
      .Mappings(
           m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
      );
```

Comment: AddMappingsFromAssembly doesn't seem to exist anymore in NHibernate 3 .

Comment: Wow I guess that was too straight-forward to find ;-) Thank you!